# Converting set of rows into column in R

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data set containing information regarding morphological traits of individuals of several species. Columns are about the individual id, species' name, trait types and trait values. I need to arrange the data in a manner where each traits should be as columns and species and individual id should be in rows. I have hundreds of individuals and several species

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: this is the `dcast` function, see `?dcast` and let us know what is unclear there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reshape` function as shown below

```
reshape(data,idvar = c("sample", "species"), timevar = "trait", v.names = "value", dir = "wide")
```